# File output overwrites first line - C++

Tags: c++, file, logging, output, newline

im creating a simple logging system for my program. I have a function that outputs whenever called in member functions of my program, so that whenever an action is taken it is logged into a text file. However it only seems to overwrite the first line of the file each time, when I want each action recorded on a new line.

```
void Logger::log(int level, std::string message, std::string source)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer[80];

    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    strftime(buffer,80,"%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S",timeinfo);
    std::string str(buffer);

    std::ofstream fout(source);
    if (fout.is_open())
    {
        fout<<"Logging Level: "<<level<< " - "  << str <<" - " << message <<std::endl;
        fout<<"test"<<std::endl;
        fout.close();
    }
}
```

Regardless of the number of times called, the logger only outputs (correctly) the last action taken. Can anyone let me know why this isn't working?

File output:

```
Logging Level: 1 - 15-01-2015 09:13:58 - Function called: grow()

test
```

log call example:

```
arrayLogger.log(1, "Function called: writeOut()", "logger.txt");
```

Comment: according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open if you call `std::ofstream`'s constructor, it will call the default implementation, which has open_mode set to `out` and as you can see out will always discard any contents already present in file. You should open it with `out | app`.

Comment: Much appreciated to the both of you, ill remember that in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening the file for writing each time, which overwrites any existing content.  You should either (a) open the file outside of that function, possibly by making the ofstream object a class member, and then your function will simply append to it, or (b) open the file for append, like so:

```
std::ofstream fout(source, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
```

Comment: `std::ofstream::binary`(I think the name is) could also be used, because Windows may change behaviour of handling things(even if for reading, it should be added for completness).

Comment: I would think that you would NOT want to open the file as binary, to allow std::endl to be translated appropriately for the platform, especially since the OP wasn't opening the file as binary, and apparently didn't have any problems that way.  Why introduce more complexity?  Anyway, that's all kind of beside the main point.

Comment: oh dang, true, I transfered the idea of binary file from different question. Sorry for that.